# What is the MakerBot Grip Surface lifespan?

Tags: makerbot, maintenance, adhesion

I've done a few prints on my MakerBot Replicator+ now and I'm curious if anyone else knows what the typical <strike>lifespan is</strike> signs of degradation are for the [grip surface tape](https://store.makerbot.com/parts-accessories/grip-surface-3-pack-for-replicator/)?

I'm used to using Kapton tape in the past. Which will bubble, scratch, and even tear at times, indicating that the tape should be replaced. However, this new MakerBot "Grip Tape" is a very stiff, precut material, with extruded plastic anchors to help evenly spread the tape and keep it secure on the build platform. The tape also has texturing on the top face that helps with adhesion.

So, this new tape seems somewhat impervious to bubbling, scratches, and tears. I'm curious what signs I can look out for that indicate that this new grip tape needs to be replaced.

<strike>Obviously the tape isn't a permanent solution, so what are some signs that the tape should be replaced?</strike>

Comment: I use the FFCP grip surfaces. Once I realized I could clean it with Alcohol.. a single pad will last me till my tools have cut too many holes. May be the same for makerbot.

Answer (score 2):

There's no quantitative formula for the lifespan of **any** grip material, be it tape, glue, or PEI sheet.  If you find a lack of stiction and it's not due to small changes in the Z-origin (50 microns can make a big difference in the way the first layer grabs the bed!), then replace the tape.  It's cheap.

Just to be pedantic, torn and scarred tape should be replaced :-)

Comment: Your answer is a very good general break down. However, I'm used to kapton tape. Which typically bubbles, scratches, and tears, indicating that it should be replaced. But this specific MakerBot grip tape is stiff and textured and will not encounter the same signs. So, I'm more interested in what those signs are. I'll try to reword my question. Thank you for your response though. +1 for great beginner tips